# What does error "Infinite yield possible on 'ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("Animations")'" mean in Roblox?

Tags: lua, roblox

```
local RS = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local Event = Instance.new("RemoteEvent", RS)
Event.Name = "PunchEvent"

local function FiredEvent(Player)
    local Character = game.Workspace:WaitForChild(Player.Name)
    local Animation = RS:WaitForChild("Animations"):GetChildren()[math.random(1, #RS.Animations:GetChildren())]
    print(Animation)
    local RandomAnim = Character.Humanoid:LoadAnimation(Animation)
    RandomAnim:Play()
    local Damage = script.Damage:Clone()
    if Animation.Name == "Right Arm" then
        Damage.Parent = Character:WaitForChild("Right Arm")
    end
    Damage.Disabled = false
    wait(1.4)
    Damage:Destroy()
end

Event.OnServerEvent:Connect(FiredEvent)
```

The image is clickable

[image]

Comment: A comment from @Eternal : _If a thread was yielded by a function waiting for a child, and the time out period has expired (5 seconds is the default in the case of WaitForChild), then you will get a warning that the script may not be resumed. It does not un-yield the thread or set an error status, so you are completely fine._

Answer (score 0):

The first error in the output is probably not one to ignore, sounds like the animations asset is supposed to be loaded from somewhere remote, and it is not found.

Once you have resolved that error, if the timeout problem doesn't get resolved, go to the "Explorer" panel and make sure that there exists "Animations" child. The error you asked about means that it could not find that object in the hierarchy. So, make sure ReplicatedStorage has Animations under it in the explorer pane.

Answer (score 0):

In programming, "yield" means stop, or in your case, wait. If you look at your output, the first error said that the animations failed to load. Since your code Waits for the animations to load, you are being warned that your code might (and probably will) wait forever, or infinitely, for the animations to load.